# how to use Google.API.Translate

Tags: c#-4.0

how to use Google.API.Translate  to translate to other language i tried below code but i got error on Translator//does not exit in current context error.where i made error

```
 using Google.API.Translate;// name space
        string text = "我喜欢跑步。";
        string translated = Translator.Translate(text, Language.Chinese, Language.English);
        Console.WriteLine(translated);
```

Comment: does not exit in current context

Comment: no method? code looks strange